# Oracle insert() function like mysql's

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Does oracle have an equivalent function like mysql's Insert() to handle strings ?

**EDIT:**
*This is the coded answer in order to be easily understood*

```
create or replace function fn_insert(ori_string in varchar2, in_pos in number, 
p_length in number, new_string in varchar2) 
    return varchar2
    is 
     resul varchar2(250) default '';
    begin
    if in_pos < 0 then
      resul := ori_string;
    else
      resul := substr(ori_string, 1, in_pos-1)||new_string||substr(ori_string, in_pos+p_length, length(ori_string) - ((in_pos+p_length)-1));
    end if;
    return resul;

    END fn_insert;
    /
```

Comment: No. But it shouldn't be too hard to create an equivalent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it manually.  So, `insert(ori_string, in_pos, length, new_string)` could be written as:

```
 substr(ori_string, 1, in_pos)||new_string||substr(orig_string, in_pos+length, length(orig_string) - (in_pos+length))
```

In other databases, this function is also called `stuff()`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm migrating a large database and I've found this function a couple of times in the origin's database so I will create a custom function with this code so I can replace it on the script.

Comment: I would add to the question the function i've created in order to people can easily use it.